# How do get the pixel color of the underlying object inside my offscreen framebuffer in opengl es 3+?

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, qml

I have 2 visual objects, the 1st contains a background image, the 2nd overlays this with information. Now I would need for each pixel in the fragment shader of the 2nd, the underlying color value of the 1st object. The construction is done with Qt Qml, (1st object = image, 2nd object a qquickframebufferobject) and I use defeered rendering. Does maybe someone knows how to go there?

Comment: Generally, you don't have the access to previously rendered samples, unless it was rendered to a texture, and you're doing second pass with that texture binded for sampling. Why do you need that info anyway? Is alpha blending/clipping not enough for your task?

Comment: Thxs Vlad! I'would use the underlying pixel color to get for my pixel the color with the highest contrast. E.g. If the underlying pixel color = white then my one should be black. Is there maybe another way?

Comment: Isn't this what https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt is for?

Comment: @Andrea: Thats exactly what I'm looking for. But if I want to include GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch via #extension in my fragment shader i always get the error "Warning: Extension 'GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions' not supported". I checked the extensions via app and found only GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch. So why exists GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch but can't use the features of it?

Comment: @PowerNow Is that just from adding the #extension line? It could be some other change you made which causes the error.

Comment: I only inserted the '#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : enable'.

Comment: Hmm. And you don't have `#extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions` anywhere, or the keywords `origin_upper_left` or `pixel_center_integer`?

Comment: In any case, that's just a warning, so if you can't figure out how to fix it (it's possible Qt is modifying your shader somehow and causing the problem) you can just ignore it I assume.

Comment: Unfortunately the warning leads to not compiling the fs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) extension for this.

In OpenGL ES 2.x the usage is something like this (silly shader I know, just for example):

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
precision mediump float;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_LastFragData[0] * 0.5;
}
```

In OpenGL ES 3.x the usage is something like this:

```
#version 300 es
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
precision mediump float;
inout vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    fragColor = fragColor * 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I tried both versions but unfortunately I always get the same message with 'GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions' is not supported. It seems so as you mentioned that's something with Qt settings. I also wondering why I can't found this package on my smartphones with opengl es +3.1, probable they are already included in the core package?

Comment: Is it a warning or an error, though? If it's a warning then you can just ignore it.

Comment: It's an warning and does subsequently not compile the FragShader.

Answer (score 0):

Here from my console...

```
W Camara  : QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): 1:2: P0003: Warning: Extension 'GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions' not supported
W Camara  : 4:1: P0003: Extension 'GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch' not supported
W Camara  : *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W Camara  : #version 300 es
W Camara  : #ifdef GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
W Camara  : #extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable
W Camara  : #extension GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced : enable
W Camara  : #endif
W Camara  : #ifndef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
W Camara  : #define highp mediump
W Camara  : #endif
W Camara  : #line 1
W Camara  : #extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
```